# I dont know how to solve: "TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: DecimateModifier.ratio expected a float type, not _PropertyDeferred"

Tags: python, modifiers, add-on

As part of the add-on, I am creating I am trying to decimate the selected object with the decimate (collapse) modifier and have a pop-up dialog box for the user to input the keep ratio. I keep getting this error even though I am defining "number" as a float previously. I found similar questions in the answer but none of the solutions worked for me.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator


class decimate_mesh(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Modify the Density of Head Mesh"
    bl_idname = 'braincapgen.decimate_mesh'

    number = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "Decimate Ratio", default = 1)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.number = number
        obj = bpy.context.object
        mod = obj.modifiers.new(name='decimate', type='DECIMATE')
        mod.decimate_type = 'COLLAPSE'
        mod.ratio = number
        mod.realtime = True
        #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].ratio = 1  ###

        return{'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):

        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(decimate_mesh)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(decimate_mesh)
```

Comment: replace `=` with `:` in `number = bpy.props.FloatProperty()`

Comment: @Karan Thank you for the response it is working better but now I am getting this error-    line 11, in execute
    self.number = number
NameError: name 'number' is not defined

Comment: its `number = self.number`, `self.number` is the property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator


class XX_OT_decimate_mesh(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Modify the Density of Head Mesh"
    bl_idname = 'braincapgen.decimate_mesh'

    number : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Decimate Ratio", default=1)

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = bpy.context.object
        mod = obj.modifiers.new(name='decimate', type='DECIMATE')
        mod.decimate_type = 'COLLAPSE'
        mod.ratio = self.number

        return{'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX_OT_decimate_mesh)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX_OT_decimate_mesh)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: it works!! Thank you so much! Hours of going through the depths of the internet and you fixed it in two lines. THANK YOU!